# gulp trust-dev-cert without error, but access the page still failed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, sharepointframework

After I upgrade my **Nodejs to v9.3.0 and NPM to 5.5.1**, failed to access the gulp serve server. The browser show the **unsafe TLS security error**.
I have removed ***~.gcb-serve-data/***, and run the **gulp trust-dev-cert** without error, but I cannot find the cert in my trust certificates, I am working in **Win10**.
Following is the **gulp trust-dev-cert" output:

```
[18:30:14] Starting gulp
[18:30:14] Starting 'trust-dev-cert'...
[18:30:14] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[18:30:14] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 7.48 ms
[18:30:14] Starting subtask 'trust-cert'...
[18:30:14] Finished subtask 'trust-cert' after 79 ms
[18:30:14] Finished 'trust-dev-cert' after 90 ms
[18:30:14] ==================[ Finished ]==================
```

Comment: It seems sharepoint framework still cannot work on **Nodejs v8,v9**, I **downgrade my Nodejs to v8**, and following this instruction: *https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002*, it can work now.

Comment: in 2024 I am using Node@v16.20.2 - NPM@8.19.4 - Gulp@CLI version: 2.3.0 --- hth

Answer (score 1):

`gulp trust-dev-cert` must be executed IN the project folder.